# How to Save an HTML page layout into PDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I am using core PHP having version 5.1.6 in procedural style

How can i save an HTML page into PDF containing exact layout information?

The major with me at currently that, whenever i am trying to save a_pahe.html to pdf by clicking "Save as PDF" link/button, it saves the HTML page but have lost all the layouts that i have needed.

My exact layout of an HTML page is
[image: exact layout]

And the Generated PDF output is as like this
[image: Generated PDF Output of file]

Comment: using  php5.1? wow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dompdf library: [GitHub link](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Dompdf is an HTML to PDF converter.
Just download and install it (read the documentation),
then pass your HTML in to dompdf and stream the output:

```
// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml(file_get_contents('exemple.html'));

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media)

```
@media print {
   /* styles go here */
}
```

You can also do it on the [link tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp) with external css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Comment: but I don't want to print the data, i want to save in PDF

Comment: @NaveenK.Sanadhya the browser has a "save as PDF" feature on print

Answer (score 0):

Properly configurated **wkhtmltopdf** might be what you need for server side pdf rendering.